# Aggregate values if primary ID is same as related ID

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have two tables, my primary table has IDs and values like so:

| Item | ID | Values | RolledUpValues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 25 | 25 |
| 100 | 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 100 | 3 | 75 | 150 (25+50+75) |
| 100 | 4 | 100 | 100 |
| 101 | 2 | 40 | 40 |
| 101 | 3 | 80 | 120 (40+80) |

In my second table, these IDs have corresponding "Main" IDs, in PowerPivot they're related on the ID field.

| ID | MainID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 6 |

Is there a way to aggregate values up to the Item + Main ID, but only when the ID in the primary key is the same as the Main ID? (e.g. for Item 100, ID 1, 2, and 3 have a corresponding Main ID of 3. So show the non-aggregated values for ID 1 and 2, but sum the values of 1, 2, and 3 for ID 3, all rolling up to Item 100)

| ID | Values | RolledUpValues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 25 |
| 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 3 | 75 | 150 (25+50+75) |
| 4 | 100 | 100 |
| 5 | 40 | 40 |
| 6 | 80 | 120 (40+80) |

Comment: I believe I oversimplified my question, updated the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship is `Table1[ID] <-- * : 1 -- Table2[ID]`, then you can write

```
RolledUpValues =
VAR RelatedID =
    RELATED ( Table2[MainID] )
VAR RolledUp =
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            RELATED ( Table2[MainID] ) = RelatedID
                && Table1[Item] = EARLIER ( Table1[Item] )
        ),
        Table1[Values]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Table1[ID] = RelatedID, RolledUp, Table1[Values] )
```

Comment: I think I oversimplified my example initially. Does it add a lot more complexity to the solution if my Table1 is structured slightly different in my new example? So rather than aggregating to just ID, it'd aggregate to Item + ID?

Comment: In that case, you need to add  a condition in your FILTER table : `Table1[Item] = EARLIER ( Table1[Item] )`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your first table is named `Table` and your second table is named `Table1`, this calculated column should work in `Table`.
Also, you should have an active relation on `ID`.

```
RolledUpValues = 
VAR SelectedMainId =
    RELATED ( Table1[MainID] )
VAR SelectedId =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( Table1, [MainID] = SelectedMainId ), [ID] )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( FILTER ( 'Table', [ID] IN SelectedId ), [Values] )
RETURN
    IF ( [ID] = SelectedMainId, Result, [Values] )
```

[image]